# Is there an IATA airport code for the Bay Area?

Tags: air-travel, airports

There is an [IATA airport code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code) for the New York City area (NYC), encompassing airports such as JFK, LaGuardia etc. This can be used on some flight search sites to search from/to several airports at once.

Is there a similar airport code for the San Francisco bay area, encompassing SFO, OAK, SJC, etc.? More generally, how would I find out these "generic" codes in future?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes**, there is *a* code for the Bay Area: **QSF**, which covers SFO, OAK and SJC.  These are called "Metropolitan area airport codes", and [Wikivoyage has the full list](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Metropolitan_area_airport_codes).

However, there's an important caveat: unlike "NYC", this particular code is not actually an *IATA* code, it's just convenient shorthand for some airline booking systems (GDS).  "QSF" will thus work on Sabre and ITA, but not other systems, where "QSF" may also be an obscure airport in Algeria.  Wikipedia has a (partial) list of *bona fide* [IATA metropolitan codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code).

Comment: Great, thanks! Exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: An IATA code for SF/BA airports would have been really helpful. :)

Comment: was looking for something that works on Hipmunk and this does it (Hipmunk expands it to the three airports though). Thanks!